# cannot resolve symbol 'MyGcmListenerService' and 'MyInstanceIDListenerService'

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm new to `android` app developing and I'm following these step from [Set up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) in the line `29`,`36` it keep saying cannot resolve symbol `MyGcmListenerService` and cannot resolve symbol
`MyInstanceIDListenerService`.

```
  <service
        android:name="com.example.MyGcmListenerService" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<this
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.example.MyInstanceIDListenerService" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<this
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Do I have to make these files ? and how to make the file ? or another way how to solve this problem

I'm really sorry if this question is too simple, but I have been stuck with this problem for a few days so I really appreciate for all the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to **write your own Java class** for *MyGCMListenerService* and *MyInstanceIDListenerService*, and include it under *Manifest.xml* like this.

```
<service
    android:name="<package-name>.MyGcmListenerService"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name="<package-name>.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try make it.